# resultado de fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

estoy consumiendo una api con fetch

```
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8000/login'
function login(email, password) {
var request = endpoint + '?email=' + email + '&password=' + password
return fetch (request)
.then(request => {
    return request.json()
})
.then(data => {

    return data 
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))}

token = login("jhonalmo23@gmail.com","1234")
console.log(token)
```

pero cuando imprimo el resultado me da un objeto el cual no se como extraer el json de result [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes usar `then` al hacer el llamado a `login("jhonalmo23@gmail.com","1234").then(res => console.log(res))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tú tienes una promesa que debes esperar que se resuelva, puedes usar `async/await`

En este ejemplo se crea una función `async Init()` donde se llama al login

```
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8000/login'
function login(email, password) {
  var request = endpoint + '?email=' + email + '&password=' + password
  return fetch (request)
  .then(request => request.json())
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

async function Init(){
 let token = await login("jhonalmo23@gmail.com","1234")
 console.log(token)
}
Init();
```

Otra forma es usar un `callback`, es decir una función que se ejecute cuando terminó el fetch, a mí me gusta más esta forma, porque creo es más "legible" (pero es cosa de gustos)

```
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8000/login'
function login(email, password) {
var request = endpoint + '?email=' + email + '&password=' + password
return fetch (request)
.then(request =>  request.json())
.then(data => SetToken(data))
.catch(error => console.log(error))
}

let token;
function SetToken(t){
  token = t;
  console.log(token)
}
login("jhonalmo23@gmail.com","1234")
```